# how to use primeNg calendar "locale" for more than one value or dynamically and also change firstdate automaticaly?

Tags: calendar, locale, primeng, angular9

based on it for e.g if locale is france week day is from monday to sunday if german de its from saturday to sun
how can i use more than one in locale

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value" [locale]="fr\de/?/??what i write here"></p-calendar>
```

//on ts file

```
this.de = {
      firstDayOfWeek: 1,
      dayNames: [, "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday","Sunday"],
      dayNamesShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
      dayNamesMin: ["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],
      monthNames: [ "January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December" ],
      monthNamesShort: [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ],
      today: 'Today',
      clear: 'Clear',
      dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
      weekHeader: 'Wk'
  };

this.fr = {
      firstDayOfWeek: 0,
      dayNames: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
      dayNamesShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
      dayNamesMin: ["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],
      monthNames: [ "January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December" ],
      monthNamesShort: [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ],
      today: 'Today',
      clear: 'Clear',
      dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
      weekHeader: 'Wk'
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in commponent .ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar-demos',
  templateUrl: './calendar-demos.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar-demos.component.scss']
})
export class CalendarDemosComponent implements OnInit {
  value: Date;
  fday:number;
  _localeCal: any;
  x=Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;

  constructor() { 
    if(this.x=='Asia/Calcutta'){
      this.fday=1;
    }
    else if(this.x==' Europe/Paris'||'USA'||'Canada/Pacific'){
      this.fday=0;
    }
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
    console.log(offset);
    console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone);
    this._localeCal = {
      firstDayOfWeek:this.fday,
      dayNames: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
      dayNamesShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
      dayNamesMin: ["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],
      monthNames: [ "January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December" ],
      monthNamesShort: [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ],
      today: 'Today',
      clear: 'Clear',
      dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
      weekHeader: 'Wk'
  };

}


}
```

here we simply checking for time zone  by using getTimezoneOffset() js fun.store  it in variable and pass  to firstweek day by checking condition on constructor to revoke automatically..console to see outcome. you can modify else if condition as your need.


in componen.html

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value" [locale]="_localeCal"></p-calendar>

calendar for utc region {{x}}
```

if  you know other  way please feel free  to response.
thanks